# Pull data from one tab to the other

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 tabs and I want to get the information from TAB2 to TAB1. I want to get the RETAIL Price from TAB2 and place it in TAB1. The condition to get the correct price is that it should be based on the ITEM CODE and SIZE of the item from TAB1 and get the same from TAB2.

Here's a demo Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CFTYCokv7teHVYDZOPquj1r0n7ZTQV3XYqrCM-EPLAk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to use a compound key in a lookup formula like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup( A3:A & B3:B, { F3:F & G3:G, I3:I }, 2, false ) ) )`

Place the formula in cell `D3` in your sample spreadsheet.

To use the formula in your real spreadsheet, modify the range references like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup( A3:A & B3:B, { 'Items list'!A2:A & 'Items list'!B2:B, 'Items list'!D2:D }, 2, false ) ) )`

The bit in curly braces is an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

Comment: Ok, I will try that as soon as I get home. Thanks!

Comment: You got it, thank you very much! One less problem to worry.